# Draggable stops wheel events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop zone and a draggable element:

```css
.drag-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #888;
  padding: 20px;
}

[draggable] {
  display: block;
  background: teal;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="drag-area">
    <ul>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
      <li>Drop area</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <dov draggable="true">drag me</dov>
</div>
```

The drop zone has `overflow-y: auto` and in it a list of elements which can grow larger than the height of the dropzone, thus the scroll. - However, when dragging an element over the drop zone, the scroll stops working and the `wheel` event stops firing altogether. I would like to be able to drag the element to the drop zone and still be able to scroll it before I drop the element.

I've searched and I can't seem to find related answers, thanks very much.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/XdQPvJ